# PyTorch - Efficient way to apply different functions to different 'row/column' of a tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

Let's say I have a 2-d tensor:

```
x = torch.Tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

Is there an efficient way to apply one function to the first 'row' [1, 2] and apply a second different function to the second row [3, 4]? (Doesn't have to be a row, could be across any dimension)

At the moment, I use the following code: Say I have my two functions, f and g, for example,

```
def f(z):
    return 2 * z
def g(z):
    return 0.5 * z
```

Then, to apply them to seperate rows I would do:

```
torch.cat([f(x[0]).unsqueeze(0), g(x[1]).unsqueeze(0)], dim = 0)
```

which gives the desired tensor [[2, 4], [1.5, 2]].

Obviously, in this 2-d example this solution is fine, but it seems a bit clunky. Is there a better way of doing this? Particularly in higher dimensions or when there are a large number of elements in the chosen dimension

Comment: If it's just the clunkiness that's the issue, you could push the split and concatenation steps inside the function instead of doing it outside.

Answer (score 1):

A handy tip is to slice instead of selecting to avoid the unsqueeze step. Indeed, notice how `x[:1]` keeps the indexed dimension compared to `x[0]`.

This way you can perform the desired operation in a slightly shorter form:

```
>>> torch.vstack((f(x[:1]), g(x[1:])))
```

Optionally you can use [`vstack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.vstack.html) to not have to provide `dim=0` to [`torch.stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stack.html).

---

Alternatively, you can use a helper function that will apply both `f` and `g`:

```
 >>> fn = lambda a,b: (f(a), g(b))
```

And split the tensor inline with [`torch.Tensor.split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.split.html#torch.split):

```
 >>> torch.vstack(fn(*x.split(1)))
```